# how to secure page methods being called from JQuery?

Tags: jquery, pagemethods

I just have started ajax using jquery and static page behind methods.

As jquery code is visible on client side, please guide how I can hide page url and its method name. I mean to ask is this way this page and static method is open to every one, can something be done to secure it ?

Thanks for guiding.

Comment: If I turn on firebug, or if I turn on wireshark, how can the php url be hidden? I think you need other way to secure your site / data

Comment: @user576510, If you found my answer helpful, would you mind marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can secure an AJAX call using the usual HTTPS protocol, but its impossible to hide your method or URL you are calling, at least *entirely hide* it. You can obfuscate your code of course, using something like [packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/), but again, as you said, since jQuery is all client-side, whoever is accessing the page will know what's going on, at least to some extent.

Comment: Thanks @jerluc, Can you please explain how to secure Ajax call using HTTP protocols ?

Comment: I'm literally just referring to your standard HTTPS SSL-secured connection. So if you have an SSL certificate signed for your domain, make your POST call to `https://yourdomain.com/yourpage...` and it will secure the client connection to the server for that call. This will not hide anything from the user though, rather it is just to secure the connection from being captured elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

No, absolutely nothing can be done to "secure" it. You've given the code to the client. The client needs to be able to execute the code. Thus, the client needs to be able to understand the code. Thus, you're boned.

Simply pulling up FireBug, Fiddler, Charles, or any other debugging proxy will tell the client immediately what the URL(s) are.

FireBug, Chrome Developer Tools, IE Developer Tools will all show you all the JS methods defined on a page or in an object. So you're out of luck on that count as well.

JS "obfuscation" is, for all intents and purposes, useless.